# Postgres - Update running count whenever row meets a certain condition

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the following entries in them

```
id price quantity
1.  10   75
2.  10   75
3.  10   -150
4.  10   75
5.  10   -75
```

What I need to do is to update each row with a number that is the number of times the running total has been 0. In the above example, the cumulative totals would be

```
id. cum_total
 1.   750
 2.  1500
 3.     0
 4.   750
 5.     0
```

Desired result

```
id price quantity seq
1.  10   75        1
2.  10   75        1
3.  10   -150      1 
4.  10   75        2
5.  10   -75       2
```

I'm now lost in a spiral of CTEs and window functions and figured I'd ask the experts.

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option using analytic functions:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN SUM(price*quantity) OVER (ORDER BY id) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS price_sum
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(price_sum, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) price_sum_lag
    FROM cte
)

SELECT id, price, quantity, 1 + SUM(price_sum_lag) OVER (ORDER BY id) cumulative_total
FROM cte2
ORDER BY id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

You may try running each CTE in succession to see how the logic is working.

Comment: This totally worked on the first go so accepting this as the answer. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

With window functions:

```
SELECT id, price, quantity,
       coalesce(
          sum(CASE WHEN iszero THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
             OVER (ORDER BY id
                   ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
          0
       ) + 1 AS batch
FROM (SELECT id, price, quantity,
             sum(price * quantity) OVER (ORDER BY id) = 0 AS iszero
      FROM mytable) AS subq;
```

Comment: Perhaps my question was not properly worded but this didn't give the results I expected. Am editing the question now so that it's more clear to anyone who reads it later.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test my query. I had to change the outer window function, now it should work.